# Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'mainfunction'

Tags: python, function, testing, pytest

**`project/tests/tests_app.py`**

```
from mainfunction import *

class TestApp:
    def test_kali(self, numbers):
        res = dikalikan_dua(numbers[0])
        assert res == numbers[1]

    def test_bagi(self, numbers):
        res = dibagi_dua(numbers[1])
        assert res == numbers[0]
```

**`project/mainfunction.py`**

```
import sys
import pytest
# from tests.tests_spam_app import dikalikan_dua, dibagi_dua


@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b, c", [(10,20, 30), (20,40,60), (11,22,33)])
def test_add(a, b, c):
    res = add(a, b)
    assert res == c

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    return a - b

def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b

def divide(a, b):
    return a * 1.0 / b

@pytest.fixture
def numbers():
    a = 10
    b = 20
    return [a,b]

def dikalikan_dua(x):
    return multiply(x, 2)

def dibagi_dua(x):
    return divide(x, 2)

@pytest.mark.easy_operation
def test_add():
    # penjumlahan
    assert add(4, 8) == 12

@pytest.mark.easy_operation
def test_subtract():
    # pengurangan
    assert subtract(3, 6) == -3

@pytest.mark.difficult_operation
def test_multiply():
    # perkalian
    assert multiply(5, 5) == 25

@pytest.mark.difficult_operation
def test_divide():
    # pembagian
    assert divide(21, 3) == 7


def main():
    num = int(input("masukan angka: "))
    print("kelipatan dari %d adalah %d" % (num, dikalikan_dua(num)))
    print("setengah dari %d adalah %d" % (num, dibagi_dua(num)))
    sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'mainfunction'
File "C:\magang\bimbingan\pak roly\zaky-function-main\tests\tests_spam_app.py", line 1, in <module>
from mainfunction import *

i dont know how i can solve this error cause I try with run program on vsc or run with command pytest but still same, please anyone can help???

Comment: The overall structure seems incorrect. The convention is that the tests are in the root of the project in the `tests` folder. In the `tests` folder, all the `@pytest.fixture`s will be in the `conftest.py` file and all the tests will be in files and folders starting with `test_`. The main function should not be in a test file or folder.

Comment: Back to your question, try importing `from project.mainfunction import *`. Or it can be that you `working directory` is not set to the root of the project in execution time.